# Problems using a rest api .jar in docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

Basically, I added code to an already existing REST API (`java`, `Springboot`). when I run it on `Intellij` there's no problem and I can use it as intended.
The thing is that I want to test it on a Docker container.
I builded the `.jar` of the project by using 
`Build->Build Artifact->project_name.jar->Build`
and when I try to `docker-compose up` I get several problems.

The folder I use contains : a `docker-compose.yml`, a `Dockerfile`, and the `.jar`
I know the first two files are ok as I used them to run a small test project and had no errors.

The first problem I got when building the container is :
`no main manifest attribute, in /project_name.jar`

My `MANIFEST.MF` look like this in my IDE :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.project.project_name.adapters.api.Application
```

but in my `.jar` artifact look like this :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: spring-beans
Automatic-Module-Name: spring.beans
Implementation-Version: 5.2.3.RELEASE
Created-By: 1.8.0_232 (Oracle Corporation)
```

So my first question is why is it different and why is it deleting the part with the  `Main Class` ? And of course how to solve this problem ?

As a temporary solution, I added the `Main Class` in the `MANIFEST.MF` by hand in my `.jar`

By doing so, I get a `MANIFEST.MF` that look like this :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.project.project_name.adapters.api.Application
Implementation-Title: spring-beans
Automatic-Module-Name: spring.beans
Implementation-Version: 5.2.3.RELEASE
Created-By: 1.8.0_232 (Oracle Corporation)
```

When I try to `docker-compose up` once again, I get this error :
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META -INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.`

I'm not really a pro in `Springboot`, and that's an ex-coworker who did the first part of the project, but I'm pretty sure it uses custom packaging.

the file `spring.factories` look like this  :

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInfoFactory=org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory
```

and I don't know if this is supposed to be correct or not.
I'm clearly missing something but I don't really know what, even after looking here for similar problem and potential solution, but nothing did the trick.

Just in case here's my pom.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.piroux</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenixrh-backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.piroux.phoenixrhbackend.adapters.api.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.bechte.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner</artifactId>
            <version>4.12.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Not sure if any other information is needed, but if so just tell me.

Comment: 1. Remove `maven-compiler-plugin` and specify `java.version` in `<properties>` in yourbuild. 2. Remove `version` from `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and `spring-boot-starter-test`. 3. Remove `junit` dependency, 4. remove `version` from `mysql-connector-java`. Use maven to build the jar don't use the export version of your IDE (which appears to be used in this case, to create a jar), just run `mvn package`.

Comment: Adding on to the last part of what @M.Deinum said, Maven is a build automation tool. The `mvn package` command can be used to produce an executable JAR in most cases (in the target/ directory). Defining an artifact in IntelliJ circumvents the whole build process defined by Maven and your POM, which is probably why you're running into trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the anwsers. I tried your solution @M.Deinum and it seems both error are gone. But now I get ```java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/project/project_name/adapters/api/Application has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 54.0```
Is this linked to any of the changes made ?

Comment: Apparently you compiled with java 11 and run on java 10. You probably forgot to include the `java.version` property as I mentioned (see my actual answer for the needed `pom.xml`).

Comment: nope, i had ```<properties><java.version>10</java.version></properties>``` ; but even after copy-pasting your answer I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I builded the .jar of the project by using
> Build->Build Artifact->project_name.jar->Build

Which is the cause of your problems. You should use the build file provided with the project. In this case the `pom.xml` to build the artifact. You should run `./mvnw package` which will create the proper jar file with the dependencies and proper files.

If you do it the way you do, you will only get a jar with the classes, with no repacked structure nor dependencies. You basically skip the whole Spring Boot thing.

**Pro Tip** Cleanup your `pom.xml` as there are some discrepancies in there.

1. Remove the `maven-compiler-plugin` and specify the version through properties. Spring Boot already sets up this plugin for you
2. Remove the `version` of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` you want to use the same version as the `parent` you provided.
3. Remove the `junit` dependency, this is already included in `spring-boot-starter-test`
4. Remove the `version` from the `mysql` dependency, it is an old one and Spring Boot manages a proper, recent version.
5. Remove the `version` of the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency, use the same version as the parent. If you leave it like this and upgrade the parent you have a version mismatch.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.piroux</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenixrh-backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>10<java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.piroux.phoenixrhbackend.adapters.api.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.bechte.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner</artifactId>
            <version>4.12.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```